# Oracle SQL sum of sums

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

Query

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE A WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE A,
SUM(CASE B WHEN B = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE B,
SUM(CASE C WHEN C = D THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE C
FROM TABLE SAMPLE_1 S_1 LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_2 S_2 ON (S_1.ID = S_2.ID)
WHERE NUMBER = '12345'
```

How do I make a column towards the end that returns the sum of all the conditional sums. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not valid SQL to start with. Sample data and desired results would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter, your code is not valid SQL. Maybe you meant:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C = D THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_C
FROM TABLE SAMPLE_1 S_1 
LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_2 S_2 ON S_1.ID = S_2.ID
WHERE NUMBER = '12345'
```

This basically assums that `A`, `B` and `C` are columns from one of the two tables involved in the query. I would highly recommend qualifying them with a table alias to make this unambigous. Also not that `NUMBER` is a reserved word in Oracle - hopefully this is not your actual column name, otherwise it needs to be surrounded with double quotes.

Now, if you want another column that sums the three conditions, that might be:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_A,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_B,
    SUM(CASE WHEN C = D THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_C,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = B OR B = C OR C = D THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_ABC
FROM TABLE SAMPLE_1 S_1 
LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_2 S_2 ON S_1.ID = S_2.ID
WHERE NUMBER = '12345'
```

That's an intersection of the three conditions, with is not necessarily the same thing as the sum of the matches in each condition. If so, either repeat the expressions, or use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*, CASE_A + CASE_B + CASE_C AS CASE_ABC
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_A,
        SUM(CASE WHEN B = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_B,
        SUM(CASE WHEN C = D THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CASE_C
    FROM TABLE SAMPLE_1 S_1 
    LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_2 S_2 ON S_1.ID = S_2.ID
    WHERE NUMBER = '12345'
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the `+` as follows in your query (`CASE` statement is also corrected) :

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ SUM(CASE WHEN B = C THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
+ SUM(CASE WHEN C = D THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS sum_of_all_condition
FROM TABLE SAMPLE_1 S_1 LEFT JOIN SAMPLE_2 S_2 ON (S_1.ID = S_2.ID)
WHERE NUMBER = '12345'
```